# How to change unit of measure for values ​in R

Tags: r

I would like to change the unit of measurement for the values ​​in my `Consumption` variable. See the values ​​are in `KWh/month` and I would like to change the values ​​to `KWh/day`. I want to do this because my `Waste` variable is in days, so I would like to change it to the `Consumption` variable as well.

```
df<-structure(list(Unit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `Waste (m3/day)` = c(239.936, 
422.18352, 5.863376, 23.9936, 406.09168, 143.9616, 42.348704, 
61.67968, 12.956544, 182.058268), `Consumption (KWh/month)` = c(14021, 
23856, 5286, 14021, 22155, 66791, 3214, 5959, 6309, 35969)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> df

    # A tibble: 10 x 3
    Unit `Waste (m3/day)` `Consumption (KWh/month)`
   <dbl>            <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1     1           240.                       14021
 2     2           422.                       23856
 3     3           5.86                       5286
 4     4           24.0                       14021
 5     5           406.                       22155
 6     6           144.                       66791
 7     7           42.3                       3214
 8     8           61.7                       5959
 9     9           13.0                       6309
10    10           182.                       35969
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that one month is 30.4167 days, you can divide that like this:

```r
df<-structure(list(Unit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `Waste (m3/day)` = c(239.936, 
                                                                                 422.18352, 5.863376, 23.9936, 406.09168, 143.9616, 42.348704, 
                                                                                 61.67968, 12.956544, 182.058268), `Consumption (KWh/month)` = c(14021, 
                                                                                                                                                 23856, 5286, 14021, 22155, 66791, 3214, 5959, 6309, 35969)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rename(Consumption = `Consumption (KWh/month)`, Waste = `Waste (m3/day)`) %>% # rename columns if you want
  mutate(Consumption = Consumption/30.4167)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>     Unit  Waste Consumption
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1     1 240.          461.
#>  2     2 422.          784.
#>  3     3   5.86        174.
#>  4     4  24.0         461.
#>  5     5 406.          728.
#>  6     6 144.         2196.
#>  7     7  42.3         106.
#>  8     8  61.7         196.
#>  9     9  13.0         207.
#> 10    10 182.         1183.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>